# ScrollView does not come back to the beginning of layout - Android

Tags: android, scrollview

How do I make a `ScrollView` always come back to the beginning? I have a `ScrollView`, and inside it a `LinearLayout` (vertical) with a `TextView` and a `Button` called "next". This button changes the `TextView` text, however the text is not shown at the beginning, but always of where it was visible on screen when the button was clicked. The user then has to scroll to see the beginning of the text.

Is there a way to make the `ScrollView` go back to the begging when the button is clicked?

Thank you

Comment: Let me know if I am correct in your layout you have a textView and a button, on clicking the button you're changing the text of textView. Now you want to go the beginning of text in the textView or you want to vertically scroll the view back to top

Comment: Just call `scrollTo(0,0)` on your `Scrollview`.

Comment: @sumit  Thx, I wanna go to beginning of text. My textView can receive a big text or a small one, then when I click in next button sometimes (when texts are different sizes) just appears the end of new text, I would like that were shown the beggining, this way the user do not need to scroll the screen to start to read.

Comment: @David Wasser I did not find out scrollTo(0,0), I found this android:scrollX="0px", but do not work :( Thx too.

Comment: @David Wasse WOW, I got what you said, `scrollView.scrollTo(0,0)`, works nicely, really thx.

Comment: Cool. Added as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `scrollTo(0,0)` on your `Scrollview`.